# Why are multiple cores engaged on sequential algorithms?

Tags: c#, cpu, amd-processor

When I run bubblesorts, cocktailsorts and quicksorts in C#, I can see that all 3 cores are engaged on my AMD X3 (X4 shipped with 1 broken core).

Why is this happening? My algorithm is sequential and my code doesn't have any thread tags. Especially something like sorting algorithms which is a highly sequential algorithm no, one event can't happen until the next is completed. How does it manage to split up the algorithm?

The bubblesort for example on request:

```
 public void BubbleSort()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < amount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
                {
                    t = numbers[j + 1];
                    numbers[j + 1] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = t;
                }
             }
          a--;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can potentially swap cores on a context switch.   But will only use one at a time.

Comment: Ah I see, well I thought about that but noticed that all cores never went down to 0%, but I'm using my taskmanager and the algorithm uses a very tight loop, so maybe I'm not able to see the period the core isn't engaged then and they stay all at 30%?

Comment: quite likely.... it would be VERY noisey graphs if they didn't smooth them out a little

Answer (score 1):

Sorting algorithms can be made to run in parallel and utilize multiple cores.  Which sort routines are you using?  It's very possible that they are not sequential algorithms.

As an example, Quicksort is very easy to [parallelize via divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Parallelization).

Comment: this is my bubblesort, sorry for the horrible formatting, I will add it to my main post

Comment: @aurelietass That will only use one core.  Are you sure that *your program* is using the 3 cores, and not other software running on your system?

Comment: Yes, I closed everything, including this browser until all cores were at 1% or 0%, then I let it run bubblesort over an array with n = 100000, all cores went up to 30%-34% and stayed there, when the array was sorted they all went back down to 1 or 0%.

Comment: There's no evidence the program was using more than one core at a time. That the total is almost exactly 100% is strong evidence that it never used more than one core at a time.

Comment: Hi, so the fault is with the task manager (which displays the individual cores) you think?

Comment: It probably moved from core to core, so the display was technically accurate. What's strange is that it did that. Windows scheduler is usually 'sticky' and doesn't migrate applications from core to core for no reason. I wonder if you have some feature that tries to keep the cores cooler by spreading the load.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This would be very odd behavior - and less than desirable as well.  By moving the algorithm from core to core, you're losing all of the advantages of cache coherency, which is likely going to dramatically reduce the algorithm's speed.  I suspect something else is going on too...

Comment: @ReedCopsey It won't dramatically reduce the algorithm's speed unless it's implemented in a broken way. Sane schedulers limit the frequency of such moves to the point where the cost of the context switches are insignificant. (For example, moving only when the thread blocks or uses up an entire timeslice.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If it's context switching enough to look like solid usage, it's likely that it's getting very little cache coherency.  It'd be interesting to try with a repro, but it doesn't do this on my machine...

Comment: @ReedCopsey 200 context switches per second has only a negligible affect on performance on a modern, quad-core machine. And scheduler parameters are designed around the cost of a context switch.